# OpenFermion to Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, simulation, hamiltonian-simulation, openfermion

Is there a direct way to go from an object generated in OpenFermion to objects usable in Qiskit? I can't find anything about any plugin.

It's not too hard to translate into pyQuil and then to Qiskit from there, but a direct way would be much easier.

Comment: There seems to be [some functionality](https://github.com/quantumlib/OpenFermion/pull/63) for converting to QASM, which can be directly read into Qiskit, using `QuantumCircuit.from_qasm_str()`. I'm unfamiliar with OpenFermion so I don't know how useful this converter is

Comment: @Andrew Jackson, how exactly would you convert a Pauli string from pyquil to qiskit format?

Comment: The easiest way if you just want to convert and not get to complicated is to use the tiKet library from CQC. It has functions to convert circuits from and to both PyQuil and Qiskit so you can just use it as an intermediary.

Comment: Please provide a specific example of the ***type of object*** that you want to generate in OpenFermion and use in Qiskit.